# One fa icon with two links

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I make a menu that should look like this:

[image]

But the last action (Auth) has a problem That's what I get:

[image].

The first image is quite wide and not fitting well into the space Stack Overflow provides. Here is [that image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uLe8.png), which shows what OP wants things to look like.

My code:

```css
.navbar-nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #d1d1d1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #efa843;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-right: 32px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="header_menu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i> Мои желания</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i> Корзина</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <i class="fas fa-user fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Вход</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Регистрация</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please give me a hint, I understand why this is happening, but I don`t know how fix this problem

Comment: It would be better if you could crop the first image to the same dimensions as your first so that we don't have to play "spot the difference". Also, please explain what you mean by your title.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve that setting the icon inside the anchor tag and also setting the other label in a span or div:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#">
   <i class="fas fa-user fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>Вход
   <!-- Here you set the other label in the same link -->
   <span>Регистрация</span>
</a>
```

Also in the css when the link is hover, keep the color of that span or div:

```
.navbar-nav li a:hover span{
  color: #d1d1d1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. Please see the live example below.

```css
.navbar-nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #d1d1d1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btnText span a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover,
.btnText span a:hover {
  color: #efa843;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.btnText {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.icon {
  color: #D1D1D1;
}

#parent_element:hover>.icon {
  color: #efa843;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="header_menu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i> Мои желания</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i> Корзина</a>
          </li>

          <div id="parent_element">
            <i class="fas fa-user fa-2x icon" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"></i>
            <div class="btnText">
              <span><a href="#">Вход</a></span>
              <span><a href="#">Регистрация</a></span>
            </div>
          </div>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an small mistake in your code and this solution was es working very well. This code will help you.

**Use this**

```css
    .navbar-nav li a {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #d1d1d1;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .navbar-nav li a:hover {
      color: #efa843;
    }

    .nav-item {
      margin-right: 32px;
    }
    .navbar-nav li label {
       display: inline-block;
       font-size: 18px;
       color: #d1d1d1;
       vertical-align: middle;
     }

   .navbar-nav li label:hover {
      color: #efa843;
   }
   .navbar-nav li label a{
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="header_menu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i> Мои желания</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i> Корзина</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
               <label class="nav-link" ><i class="fas fa-user fa-2x"></i>
                <span><a href="#">Вход</a></span>
              <span><a href="#">Регистрация</a></span>
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**What changes made by me**

*I will add a label tag before account icons and make a separate css for that label.*

> If you doesn't satisfied by this answer or this solution doesn't working correctly, please inform me.

Hope this will help you, thank you

Answer (score 0):

just add flex-shrink-0 class in li tag

```
<div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="header_menu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="flex-shrink-0 nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i> Мои желания</a>
              </li>
              <li class="flex-shrink-0 nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i> Корзина</a>
              </li>
              <li class="flex-shrink-0 nav-item">
                <i class="fas fa-user fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Вход</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Регистрация</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replaced to ".navbar-nav li a:hover" selector to ".navbar-nav li:hover a, .navbar-nav li:hover i".

```css
.navbar-nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #d1d1d1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover a, .navbar-nav li:hover i{
  color: #efa843;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-right: 32px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="header_menu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i> Мои желания</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i> Корзина</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <i class="fas fa-user fa-2x" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Вход</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Регистрация</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```